# Calculate $e^{\mathbb{A}}$ where ${\mathbb{A}}$ is the matrix of the following differential system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we have the following system of differential equations :

> > $\begin{pmatrix}
> > x\\ 
> > y
> > \end{pmatrix} '$= $\begin{pmatrix}
> > 3 &-2 \\ 
> >  2& -2
> > \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
> > x\\ 
> > y
> > \end{pmatrix}$

Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the matrix of this system , I have to calculate $\exp(\mathbb{A})$

Here is what I know :

$\exp(\mathbb{A}) = \sum{\frac{\mathbb{A}^{n}}{n!}}$

*Example for the identity :*

$\mathbb{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}\;\;$,$\; \exp(\mathbb{A})=I + \mathbb{A} +\frac{\mathbb{A}}{2} + ...... $

So :

$\exp^{\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}}= \begin{pmatrix}
 1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+.....&0 \\ 
 0&  1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+.....
\end{pmatrix} $ = $\begin{pmatrix}
e &0 \\ 
 0& e 
\end{pmatrix}$

I tried the same thing for my problem but it didn't work , any help would be a lot appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: hint: diagonalize $A$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes we've done it to find the solution of a differential equation using matrix .. my bad

Comment: The next topic is to find the exponential function of a matrix that is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

If you can write $A = VDV^{-1}$ (diagonalization), then
$$
A^2 = A\cdot A
    = \left(VDV^{-1}\right)\left(VDV^{-1}\right)
    = VD\left(V^{-1}V\right)DV^{-1}
    = VD^2V^{-1}
$$
and similarly $A^n = VD^nV^{-1}$, so you have
$$
e^A = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}
    = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{VD^kV^{-1}}{k!}
    = V \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{D^k}{k!} \right) V^{-1}
    = V e^{D} V^{-1}.
$$

Now can you diagonalize $A$, find $D$ and $V$, and plug in?